# Couldn't find enough finder patterns:0 patterns found

Tags: javascript, camera, qr-code, getusermedia

For an web application, I need to build a QR code scanner.

To do this, I have used getUserMedia to access my mobile phone camera.  I take picture, and upload its data_uri(URI) to QR Code Decoder module.  But it is throwing me the mentioned exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using following decoder which is based on Lazarsoft Jsqrcode.
https://github.com/edi9999/jsqrcode

And for camera, I have used following library
https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample code of what you have tried so that others can answer your question